# Best way to record audio with mic and send to server

Tags: javascript, silverlight, flash, apache-flex, red5

I know there are similar questions but there is no answer for me.

What is the best option for recording audio with microphone on website and send to server for some operation.

1) `java`/`javascript`

2) `red5`

3) `flash`/`flex`

4) `silverlight`

5) `other`(pls specify)

I want to create something like this : http://wami.csail.mit.edu/examples/jsapi/calculator.html

Comment: Your question is like 'Best car to buy'.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your question isn't exactly a good one.  There is no 'best technology', only what's best for your project which I know nothing about.

With that being said, there's also the fact that you're bundling both front end and back end technologies together, which doesn't work.  And what kind of 'work' do you need done on the audio.

If it was me, I'd use Flash on the front end to record the microphone since it has the most market penetration compared to say Silverlight.  Javascript cannot record the microphone.  From there, I can then send the audio (streamed or not) to the server, which in this case is really up in the air.  I could be any technology and it wouldn't matter all that much unless one language has a better audio library than the other.  If you just want to store the recording, you can use something extremely simple like PHP, but if you need something a bit more robust, you'll probably have a better time with using Java.

How Flash sends the audio to the server is up to you.  There are several options but if it doesn't need to be streamed, I'd say just upload using http.

Answer (score 2):

The technology you refer to in your example is open-source.  It uses a hidden Flash app to perform an HTTP post from client to server.  Streaming is simulated by chunking the audio into multiple POSTs.  Here's the link:

https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/